# Print tilted text on canvas without rotating the whole canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can I fillText at an angle without having to use the rotate() function on the whole canvas. Something like

```
ctx.fillText("Hi", x, y, AngleRadian);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use save and restore to be sure the whole canvas won't be affected by your operations.

Assuming you want to rotate from the middle of the text, you have to ensure the right align of the text, as @markE mentionned as the easiest way of proceeding :

jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/c6kKn

```
function fillTextRotated(text, x, y, angle) {
   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(x, y);
   ctx.rotate(angle);
   ctx.textAlign = "center";
   ctx.fillText(text, 0, 0);
   ctx.restore();
}

fillTextRotated("Hi everyone here", 50, 150, Math.PI/6);
```

output looks like :

[image]